# how to fetch content from one table according to results from another table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two mysql tables with content one is called petitions

```
{"success":1,"petitions":[{"id":"6","name":"should he go","timestamp":"2013-10-26 03:02:44"},{"id":"3","name":"Olara Otunu should get married","timestamp":"2013-10-24 14:33:53"},{"id":"4","name":"Teachers deserve 30 not 20 salary rise","timestamp":"2013-10-24 14:33:53"},{"id":"5","name":"Prostitution should be banned","timestamp":"2013-10-24 14:33:53"},{"id":"1","name":"Has Jennifer Musisi done great work for Kampala","timestamp":"2013-10-24 14:32:58"},{"id":"2","name":"Do lecturers deserve 100% salary increase","timestamp":"2013-10-24 14:32:58"}]}
```

and the other table is called petition_response

```
{"success":1,"petition_response":[{"id":"2","petitionID":"2","yes":"0","no":"1","memberID":"14","timestamp":"2013-11-02 08:36:20"},{"id":"1","petitionID":"1","yes":"1","no":"0","memberID":"14","timestamp":"2013-11-01 21:26:02"}]}
```

I need to select * petitions which have no response in the petition_response. But if they have any response in the petition_response table then the memberID should not be equal to 14

I have tried this code below but its not working

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from petition_response where memberID='14' order by timestamp DESC", $db->connect());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $id = $row['id'];

    $result2 = mysql_query("select * from petitions where id != '$id' order by timestamp DESC", $db->connect());            
}
return $result2;
```

Comment: Note that this method (mysql_) is deprecated. Use mysqli_ and/or PDO. And see about injection. And then see about JOINs.

Comment: "It's not working" is not enough to help you. What result / error do you get ?

Comment: i have tried it but still not getting the results right

Comment: Okey, but what do you get for now, and what do you expect to get ?

Comment: {"success":1,"petitions":[{"id":"6","name":"should he go","timestamp":"2013-10-26 03:02:44"},{"id":"3","name":"Olara Otunu should get married","timestamp":"2013-10-24 14:33:53"},{"id":"4","name":"Teachers deserve 30 not 20 salary rise","timestamp":"2013-10-24 14:33:53"},{"id":"5","name":"Prostitution should be banned","timestamp":"2013-10-24 14:33:53"},{"id":"2","name":"Do lecturers deserve 100% salary increase","timestamp":"2013-10-24 14:32:58"}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking to effect an anti-join, for which there are three possibilities in MySQL:

1. Using `NOT IN`:

   ```sql
   SELECT *
   FROM   petitions
   WHERE  id NOT IN (
            SELECT petitionID
            FROM   petition_response
            WHERE  memberID = 14
          )
   ```
2. Using `NOT EXISTS`:

   ```sql
   SELECT *
   FROM   petitions p
   WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM   petition_response r
            WHERE  r.petitionID = p.id
               AND r.memberID   = 14
            LIMIT  1
          )
   ```
3. Using an `OUTER JOIN`:

   ```sql
   SELECT p.*
   FROM   petitions p
            LEFT OUTER JOIN petition_response r
                         ON r.petitionID = p.id AND r.memberID = 14
   WHERE  r.petitionID IS NULL
   ```

See them on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/080ca/1).

According to [@Quassnoi's analysis](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/):

> #### Summary
>
> MySQL can optimize all three methods to do a sort of `NESTED LOOPS ANTI JOIN`.
>
> It will take each value from `t_left` and look it up in the index on `t_right.value`. In case of an index hit or an index miss, the corresponding predicate will immediately return `FALSE` or `TRUE`, respectively, and the decision to return the row from `t_left` or not will be made immediately without examining other rows in `t_right`.
>
> However, these three methods generate three different plans which are executed by three different pieces of code. The code that executes `EXISTS` predicate is about **30%** less efficient than those that execute `index_subquery` and `LEFT JOIN` optimized to use `Not exists` method.
>
> That’s why the best way to search for missing values in **MySQL** is using a `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` or `NOT IN` rather than `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "
SELECT * 
  FROM petition_response pr
  LEFT
  JOIN petitions p
    ON p.id = pr.id
 WHERE pr.memberID = 14 
   AND p.id IS NULL
 ORDER
    BY pr.timestamp DESC;
";
```